# Can a switch in the settings bundle manipulate another settings

Tags: ios, settings.bundle

I need to put a few editable URLs in the settings bundle and as there will be three I need each to have a switch to tell the web view what url I want it to load at startup.

Any ideas? The problem is that the url's need to stay in the settings part of the app and I have no ideas if the switches, text field, titles and groups can be manipulated this way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a fixed number of URLs, one could be selected via a multivalue control type (have a list of URL 1, 2 and 3 for instance) and have three text fields below saying URL 1: ..... and so on. However, if you wish to have a variable amount of URLs or switches (working as radio buttons), then I believe that in-app settings is a way better solution than the settings bundle.

Comment: Cool thanks! I just noticed that the nike app disables fields based on the state of the switch. You think this is doable or just an feature the apps that come with the phone have?

Comment: Sorry, that is not possible for 3rd party apps. Only Apple-developed apps are able to do that. As of now, the Settings bundle is quite limited, so unless you have a good reason to have all the settings in the settings bundle, I would recommend using a custom settings page in your app.